# Post to Fanpage as Fanpage it self

Tags: php, facebook

Im trying to post to a Fanpage wall as the Fanpage it self

So you will see Fanpage name Posted .... the message

i have the following code :

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageid?fields=access_token"); 

        $args = array(
                'access_token'  => $fbconfig['token2'],
                'message' => 'New Video : '.$_POST['title'].'', 
                'link'    => 'http://www.linktomysite.com',
                'picture' => 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$_POST['videouri'].'/0.jpg',
                'name'    => ''.$_POST['title'].'',
                'description'=> 'NEW video out on "Fanpage name" '.$_POST['title'].''
            );    
            $post_id = $facebook->api("/$pageid/feed","post",$args);
```

It does post on the Fanpage wall but as myself and it shows up in 
Recent Posts by Others on "Fanpage Name"

I have put in Fanpage name i do not want to advertise here :P but thats then the name of my fanpage

Does anyone knows how to Post as the fanpage it self instead of my account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of user access token ($fbconfig['token2']) use page access token ($page_info['access_token']) as explicit access token

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$pageid?fields=access_token"); 

$args = array(
    'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
    'message' => 'New Video : '.$_POST['title'].'', 
    'link'    => 'http://www.linktomysite.com',
    'picture' => 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$_POST['videouri'].'/0.jpg',
    'name'    => ''.$_POST['title'].'',
    'description'=> 'NEW video out on "Fanpage name" '.$_POST['title'].''
    );    
$post_id = $facebook->api("/$pageid/feed","post",$args);
```